# Why does Karate recommend kicking with feet instead of shins?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, technique, karate, muay-thai, krav-maga

What is the historical reason Karate and Taekwondo recommend kicking with foot instead of shins for Round kicks (different from Muay Thai)?

In Krav Maga, they teach to kick with foot, since most of the Israeli soldiers are wearing sturdy thick army boots, and the small bones will not break, while giving longer kicking range. Is there a reason, Karate and TKD recommend this? Maybe warriors wear metal samarai boots during ancient times?

I see many young adults especially in TKD learning, and last thing people want are kids having injury in self defense.

Note: Prefer post not be about which martial art is better, and more professional about understanding the historical context.

Comment: 'metal samarai boots' sound unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

From what I was taught, we kick with the feet instead of the shin because of physics. The longer a lever is, the more force it can apply. Kicking with the shin shortens the lever thus decreasing the amount of force applicable. The idea being to generate the greatest amount of force using the least amount of energy.

If you ever want an example of how much force can be applied look up "Insane KO Hook Kick" on youtube.

Furthermore when we would kick with the shin it would usually be done to leg check an opponent and weaken their leading leg.

Another reason why it's taught this way is partially because these disciplines are traditionally rigid in technique, my dojo growing up stemmed from the International TKD Alliance (afaik an off-shoot of South Korean TKD), and then our next off-shoot of that broke away from the rigidity and taught MMA.

Answer (score 2):

For tae kwon do, it basically stems from physics. If you kick with the ball of your foot for a roundhouse kick, then the bones of your foot all face your target, so support the kick. If you kick with the shin or instep (we teach to kick with the instep to start with), then you could injure your shin or instep if you kick a solid enough target with enough force.

It is also true that kicks with the feet have inherently longer range than with the shin.

You specifically asked about roundhouse kick, but the pe-chagi, or slash kick, does use the shin. That is the only tae kwon do kick I know of that uses it. Other parts of the foot are used for other kicks, though.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me.  Range is a good reason, but saying you could break your shin if you land a kick with it sounds like a terrible reason.  If there is enough force to break a shin there is also enough to break the foot irrespective of angle.  The instep I agree is fairly weak.

Comment: @HuwEvans You may break a baseball bat by hitting a steel railing with it, but try ramming the steel railing with one end of the bat. If you kick, say, someone's stronger leg with your shin hard enough, like you want to harm them, then you absolutely could break your own shin instead.

Comment: But you can't even possibly do a straight kick with the shin.  This question doesn't make sense if you compare a straight kick landing the ball with a roundhouse landing the shin.  It's about roundhouse kicks as the OP specifies.

Comment: @HuwEvans If you do a roundhouse kick with the shin the motion is the same as if you do it with the foot, except the foot position matters less because you're hitting with the shin. I don't understand the objection. You would hit at shorter distance because the shin is closer to you than the foot.

Comment: "try ramming the steel railing with one end of the bat" this is analogous to a straight kick.  roundhouse kicks are like swinging not ramming the bat.  Yes roundhouse kicks are the same shape regardless of whether you use the shin or foot to land the blow, but you are more likely to break a foot than a shin in either case.  Feet are weaker than shins regardless of angle.

Comment: @HuwEvans I think you are considering only the motion of the leg, not what is moving where at impact. If you kick with the ball foot, the bones of the foot are at a different angle than the shin, for they face the direction of motion. The same kick with instep has the bones shearing, which is always the same direction as the shin.

Comment: I don't think these angles are well defined as a concepts.  But the foot is itself made up of many fairly weak bones.  also this depends on the strength of the ancle which isn't particularly durable.

Comment: @HuwEvans I think you are talking past each other. Michael seems to say that in case a kick is blocked *with the shin*, the bones of the foot stand in an angle to the target's shin that makes it unlikely to break them. That is true. On the other hand, a) I, personally, would target the upper ankle joint with my block, not the foot, anyways and b) it doesn't change the fact that generally, all things (like **elbows**) considered, it is still much more likely to break the bones of your feet in roundhouse kicks than it is to break your shin, especially as the receiving bone gets more impact.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, thank you for chiming in. I don't mean, however, about blocking with the shin, but kicking with it. It seems tough to block someone by kicking, especially with the foot, rather than the shin.

Comment: I am fully aware what you spoke about, it just does not make much sense as a general assertion. The shin generally points in the same direction as the bones of the foot as your ankle has no rotational potential. Also, you generally kick with a part of the shin about one third down from patella towards ankle, where the shin is thick and triangular, being one of the most stable bones in our body. While I buy both the range and the speed argument (speed due to lever), structural stability certainly speaks *against* kicking with the foot in all circumstances where it matters (esp. when blocked)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, perhaps I wasn't clear. The ankle can bend so that the toes point, like a ballerina balancing on toes, or so that the foot is perpendicular to the shin, like standing normally. If the kick uses the "standing" position, using the ball-foot, all of the instep bones are in the direction of the kick. One can break a board with a roundhouse kick using the ball-foot, but you might break your instep if you try to break a board with roundhouse kick using your instep.

Comment: Yeah, but shin kicks are delivered with said point 2 thirds of the shin upwards. Not your instep, not your ankle, not your lower shin. Thus, even if you can, of course, very easily break your foot when kicking with your instep compared to kicking with the ball-foot, that still does not magically make your foot more stable compared to your shin. Hence, even a perfect foot-position leaves a kick with the foot *much* more vulnerable for injuries compared to a connection with the shin. There is a reason **all full-contact styles tend to use the shin over the foot** in roundhouse kicks.

Answer (score 1):

Karate doesn't limit its kicks to either foot or shin. Some forms of karate - such as sport-oriented styles - might emphasise feet as a means of maximising reach, but most full-contact and traditional schools train to employ the shin, top of ankle, instep, heel, both sides of the foot, ball of foot and toes.

Comment: ok cool, guess remaining question is why tkd teaches this way, etc, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to break your shin against someone who checks a kick than it is to break your foot. With your foot the impact is cushioned & absorbed some by your ankle & foot bending when checked. Your shin however has no means to disperse with some of the impact therefor taking a localized 100% of the trauma. If you are solely wanting to cause more damage with your kicks against an un trained attacker then you can dig with your shins on your kicks as it will hit & impact harder than your foot, but if you are fighting someone that knows how to check a kick then always hit with the foot, as the damage is not quite as much as your shin can cause but you aren't at risk of getting your leg broke in half either. Even without breaking your leg, the pain from a normal leg kick check with your shin will do some damage & cause swelling, welts, pain, & problems posting & applying weight to it properly. Alex Peirera is THE BEST at it. Watch his fights once he checks 1 leg kick sometimes you can see how bad it hurts his opponents that are kicking him with full shin, even as he is tearing their leg off with leg kicks himself. You can see a clear grimace on their face when he checks a leg kick & they start limping slightly just from ONE check. Watch his fight against Jiri Prochazka.

Comment: I would disagree, feet have small bones which break easier than shin, its been proven most UFC fighters use shin (which can still break but less)

Comment: That's evidently false. The shin, as structural bone, is much, **much** more stable than any foot will ever be